# How to determine, if SQL statement returns columns

Tags: sql, database, odbc

I'm writing code, which can execute SQL queries via ODBC.

For it I'm running `SQLExecDirect()`, then `SQLExtendedFetch()` to get result columns.

However statements like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` etc. don't have return columns and `SQLExtendedFetch` finishes with an error code.

The question is: how to determine from query if that kind of query has return columns or not?

`Edit`: Forget to mention, that for querys, that should not have return columns SQLGetDiagRec() returns empty error message (I'v tested it on MS SQL driver) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call SQLNumResultCols and if it says 0 you've got no result-set.